# Can't get Bootstrap gradient to work

Tags: css, less

Why is this CSS rule being rejected as `unidentified` by my LESS compiler?

```
#gradient > .vertical(#fff; #c3c3c3; 0%; 80%)
```

Comment: I just checked and it works fine mate. Can you indicate your compiler version and also provide your full code (without the bootstrap code) please?

Comment: It's a compiler "watcher" for PHPStorm 8.

Comment: Note that these mixins require the file where they are defined (i.e. those Bootstrap `mixins` files) to be visible at (imported in or imported before) the point you use it. And if you have your PHPStorm configured to compile each file you edit separately the "undefined" would be expected if the compiled file does not import those things. (In other words make sure your watcher only tries to compile the project's master file with "everything included" and not every individual less file you have/edit there).

Comment: I tried to use it in the main LESS file (the one that I import the rest of the style modules in, including bootstrap) for the gradient. It's still not working. This is puzzling.

Answer (score 0):

PhpStorm's less evaluation might be a bit more strict, so you can try it without the `>`, as it's not really part of bootstrap's gradients mixin.

Try this:

```
#gradient .vertical(#fff; #c3c3c3; 0%; 80%);
```

Comment: It's still undefined.